# fsutil setcasesensitiveinfo not working on sub Directories

Tags: windows-10, case-sensitive, fsutil

I used this command to make windows directory casesensitive.

> `fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo -destination here- enable`

It's working fine on that directory, but not on it's sub directories. I can't run this command on each and every sub-directory. Does anyone know of another way or a missing parameter maybe...